# Pandas: Printing a 'match' instead of only the Boolean result

Tags: string, pandas, dataframe

I have a column with text and a substring. The goal is to iterate trough the text and if there is a match I would like to print that match in a new column instead of solely finding a True/False statement. How does one do this? Current code:

```
sLength = len(dfEx5)
substring = ['AmericanAir', 'JetBlue', 'SouthwestAir', 'united','USAirways', 'VirginAmerica']
dfEx5['mentions'] = pd.Series(1, index=dfEx5.index) #Add a new column 'mentions' with 1's
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None #To deal with the 'SettingWithCopyWarning'

dfEx5['mentions'] = next((substring for substring in dfEx5['text'] if substring in dfEx5['text']), True)
```

Where `dfEx5['text']` is a `pandas.core.series.Series`.

Comment: You want `str.extract`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `apply` method to pass a custom function:

```
substring = ['AmericanAir', 'JetBlue', 'SouthwestAir', 'united','USAirways', 'VirginAmerica']
df= pd.DataFrame([["AmericaAir5","JetBlue2"],["JetBlue2","SouthwestAir"]],columns=['text','what'])
def searchr(x,s):
    for i in s:
        if x.find(i)+1:
            return i
        else:
            continue
df["mentions"]=df['text'].apply(searchr,args=(substring,))
```

Alternatively, You can use regex:

```
import re
r = re.compile('('+"|".join(substring)+')')
df["m"] = df.text.str.extract(r)
```

The first method seems faster than regex str concat

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I think I can accept this answer. Give me some more time to try it out.